# Recover uncommited changes in Git from accidentally switching to another branch

Tags: git, pycharm

I have a project that I have made a lot of changes to in Branch A. I never commited these changes because I was following the suggested practice of only commiting code in a working state.

Today, I made the stupid mistake of switching to another branch, forgetting to stash or commit my changes.

The code is opened up in PyCharm, and I haven't clicked on the PyCharm window to bring it into focus because I know it will listen for the changes and wipe everything out on the screen. I also have not switched back to Branch A in fear of doing any more damage.

Did I just wipe out a whole bunch of work? Am I able to recover any of it through Git or PyCharm's current state?

Comment: what do `git status` and `git diff` say?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Amish. Let's emphasize *because I was following the suggested practice of only commiting code in a working state*, not to shame you but to warn people about the consequences of such approach. Commit often.

Comment: @eftshift0 if I'm seeing this correctly, it's showing changes from Branch A (it has been a while since I looked at this other branch).

Comment: @RomainValeri Thank you Roman. I see now how foolish it was to follow this practice. I have never made this mistake before and was under the belief that I could never go on autopilot this bad.

Comment: To expand on @RomainValeri's comment: the key to understanding it is the fact it's perfectly fine (and easy) in Git to _rewrite existing history._ It means it's absolutely okay to do micro commits of whatever "broken" state there is, and then "squash" them all together once you're fine with the result — to produce one or more logically atomic beautiful well-commented commits. Just be sure to never push these "broken" commits to a branch which is supposed to be "the mainline" for the feature you're working on (or to the whole project).

Comment: @Amish just to add something : if you don't want to clutter your branch history with a lot of unsignificant commits (which is arguably at the root of the advice you followed here), just don't *push* them. Commit often *on your local environment* and when you have a working state, some specific milestone, then take a bit of time (not that much, really) to organize your commits according to your needs, then push the wanted final state of the branch.

Comment: …that is, it's fine to push them, if needed, to your "private" branch. It's absolutely normal to force-push them there again if you will rewrite them for some reason. Just make sure no one bases their work on that branch (usually that's a project's policy thing). Once the feature or a part of it—comprised by those commits—is ready, use `git rebase`/`git cherry-pick`/`git merge --squash` to make it sing and share.

Comment: I don't even understand how you'd be able to switch to another branch while uncommitted changes are in your repository. I'm always getting errors about exactly that.

Comment: @TimRandall, that's a stock Git feature, and literally lots of Git newcomers get bit by it because they do not read introductory material up front and somehow think that switching branches has to somehow automatically "stash away" uncommitted changes on _that_ branch (and resurrect them when the user switches back). Hence they ask "backwards" questions like "why I have all my local changes again after I have checked out another branch?" ;-)

Comment: @TimRandall, such checkout will of course fail _if_ any of the locally-modified files was also modified—compared to its state in `HEAD`—in the branch you're about to check out. And even then, it's possible to proceed: read the manual about the `-m` command-line option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to another branch, your changes will carry over. You just have to switch back to your branch and commit or stash.

Further more if your current change will get a conflict with the another branch, git will refuse to switch branch.

You can see your current changes with `git status`.

Somme commands can delete your works like `git clean`, `git reset`, `git checkout --force mybranch`, `git checkout .` do note the dot, this command will discard all changes in the working tree ( files that are tracked by git, files are tracked by adding them with `git add` for example.).

To summarize :

Doing a `git checkout MyBranch` does not overwrite or delete your changes

Comment: According to your answer, you state that using `git checkout` will wipe out changes. I specifically used `git checkout BranchA` because that is how I learned to switch branches. Wouldn't that mean I have wiped out my changes?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant that if you use `git checkout .` It will wipe your changes. The dot is important. I updated my answer. Doing `git checkout mybranch` is ok.

Comment: The answer should be reworded to be explicit about _this form_ of the `git checkout` command. What you've demonstrated is `git checkout` _applied to paths in the work tree` — because the dot `.` means the root of the work tree.

Comment: `git checkout --force mybranch` would also wipe local changes. But as far as I could see, PyCharm's git client does not do this. So, OP should be safe.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be more clear now. Thanks

Comment: What to do if I have merge conflicts and want them to revert and switch to the old branch?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Nitixx's answer according to the OP's request, let's cite the manual:

> `git checkout <branch>`
>
> To prepare for working on `<branch>`, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing `HEAD` at the branch. *Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept,* so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.

(emphasis mine).

So, yes, *unless* you also somehow explicitly messed with overwriring the contents of the affected files, a mere checkout of the original branch will carry your local modification over.